# Unable to carry out Software Update on OS X 10.5.8

Tags: macos, upgrade, mac-appstore, software-update, leopard

I have tried to carry out a Software Update on a Mac running **OS X 10.5.8**.

My first problem is that I am unable to find the Mac App Store on this computer (whether by using the search function or looking in the Applications folder.)

Even when I go to the Apple website and attempt to get redirected from there to the Mac App Store to find the Software Update, nothing happens.

Furthermore, the computer does not detect any Software Updates when clicking on the top-left Apple menu and selecting **Software Update**.

Comment: What model and year is your Mac? ( > About this Mac)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to purchase the DVD update from Apple to be able to get to 10.6.8. After that your next jump would either be 10.7.5 or 10.11.1 depending on the Mac model.

Comment: The reason that you're not seeing any software updates for Leopard is that support for that OS ended in mid-2012. If your Mac has a 32-bit EFI, it will be able to run Lion (also EOLed). As suggested in the answers, you'll need to get Snow Leopard install disks and get 10.6.8 happening before the App Store will show up. NOTE: Lion will only be available to you on the App Store if you have purchased it in the past; otherwise, you'll need to contact Apple. If your Mac has a 64-bit EFI, you should be okay to run El Capitan.

Answer (score 3):

Mac App Store requires OS X version 10.6.8 or higher to install. You can try updating via USB (paid upgrade) if you have an Intel x86 based processor.